# DataContract Attributes not being sent in responses

Tags: wcf, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have had it where the name/namespace/other attributes show up when sending a request, but now they have disappeared and cant figure out for the life of me what changed...  I am trying to utilize the WebApi project but the documentation seems limited.

WebServiceResource.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using wsDAL.EDataTypes;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace wsDAL
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class WebServiceResources
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetNameValueTest/{name}/{value}")]
        public NameValue GetNameValueTest(string name, string value)
        {
            NameValue nv = new NameValue("WS_" + name + "_WS", "WS_" + value + "_WS");  
            return nv;
        }
    }
}
```

GeneralResources.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Data;

namespace wsDAL.EDataTypes
{
    [DataContract(Name = "NameValueContract", Namespace = "http://fred.NameValue.com")]
    public class NameValue
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _value;

        public NameValue()
        {
            _name = null;
            _value = null;
        }

        public NameValue(string Name, string Value)
        {
            _name = Name;
            _value = Value;
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "NameMember")]
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

        [DataMember(Name = "ValueMember")]
        public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    }
}
```

Note I am using lightcore as an IOC container (kinda new to this stuff)
Was originally going of the post at [http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/04/15/Microsoft-Web-API-e28093-the-REST-is-done-by-WCF-(Part-1).aspx](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/04/15/Microsoft-Web-API-e28093-the-REST-is-done-by-WCF-%28Part-1%29.aspx)
but once I got to part six where he is returning `HttpResponseMessage<Contact>` from POSTs, it all started falling apart.  client was looking for the namespace when returning xml but that was not part of the serialized response...

Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using LightCore;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Activation;

....

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Register<IResourceFactory, LightCoreResourceFactory>();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    var configuration = HttpHostConfiguration.Create().SetResourceFactory((serviceType, instanceContext, request) => container.Resolve(serviceType), null);

    RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<WebServiceResources>("ws", configuration);

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
}

....
```

---

Ok, what it seems that I failed to realize, is that the name/namespace info gets serialized to the server, but not to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer on this... I was using a DataContractSerializer on the client which was adding the name/namespace info, while on the server I was using the default WebApi serialization which was not adding the info. Thanks for anyone who took time looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a routing table record?

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<WebServiceResources>("GetNameValueTest");
```